# Is it possible to use ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android 10.2.2 with ArcGIS Server 10.1.1

Tags: android, arcgis, esri

As the title says, is it possible to use the **ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android version 10.2.2** with service hosted on an **ArcGIS Server version 10.1.1**?

Specifically I'm trying to cache a feature from a server running at 10.1.1 onto an android device. The  caching API calls in the `com.esri.core.tasks.geodatabase` package isn't available until [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android 10.2.2](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/tasks/geodatabase/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use services from older versions of ArcGIS Server but you will only have access to the functionality exposed at that version via the REST API. It sounds like you are wanting  to use the sync framework but since this was introduced at version 10.2.2 of ArcGIS Server you will need to use that. Alternatively you can use ArcGIS Online and create a hosted feature service there with offline capability enabled.